# Load custom configuration runtime

Tags: node.js, vue.js, plugins, configuration, nuxt.js

I have a `nuxt` application in which I will need to append data from a generated configuration file when the application is first started. The reason I cannot do this in the actual build is because the configuration file does not exists at this point; it is generated just before calling `npm start` by a bootstrap script.

Why don't I generated the configuration file before starting the application you may ask and this is because the application is run in a docker container and the built image cannot include environment specific configuration files since it should be used on different environments such as testing, staging and production.

Currently I am trying to use a hook to solve this, but I am not really sure on how to actually set the configuration data in the application so it can be used everywhere:

```
# part of nuxt.config.js
  hooks: {
    listen(server, listener) {
      # load the custom configuration file.
      fs.readFile('./config.json', (err, data) => {
        let configData = JSON.parse(data));
      });
    }
  },
```

The above hook is fired when the application first starts to listen for connecting clients. Not sure this is the best or even a possible way to go.

I also made an attempt of using a plugin to solve this:

```
import axios from ‘axios’;

export default function (ctx, inject) {
  // server-side logic
  if (ctx.isServer) {
    // here I would like to simply use fs.readFile to load the configuration, but this is not working?
  } else {
    // client-side logic
    axios.get(‘/config.json’)
      .then((res) => {
        inject(‘storeViews’, res.data);
    });
  }
};
```

In the above code I have problems both with using the `fs` module and `axios`.

I was also thinking about using a middleware to do this, but not sure on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else has this kind of problem here is the solution I came up with in the end:

```
// plugins/config.js
class Settings
{
  constructor (app, req) {
    if (process.server) {
      // Server side we load the file simply by using fs
      const fs = require('fs');
      this.json = fs.readFileSync('config.json');
    } else {
      // Client side we make a request to the server
      fetch('/config')
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
          }
        })
        .then((json) => {
          this.json = json;
        });
       }
     }
}

export default function ({ req, app }, inject) {
  inject('config', new Settings(app, req));
};
```

For this to work we need to use a server middleware:

```
// api/config.js
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Here we pick up requests to /config and reads and return the
// contents of the configuration file
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile('config.json', (err, contents) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.end(contents);
  });
});

module.exports = {
  path: '/config',
  handler: app
};
```